# single xml objects as json array in sql

Tags: c#, sql

From SQL, I generated my XML and it looks like this

```
<users>
    <user>user1</user>
</users>
```

Then I converted it to JSON and it looks like this,

```
"users": { "user": "user1" }
```

but I'm expecting a JSON to look like a single object array:

```
"users": [{ "user": "user1" }]
```

Comment: root <users> is the label for your JSON object. when you have multiple <user> you will see  "user": [
   "user1",
   "user1"
  ]

Comment: when you change as multiple user object, you wont see like you want. The converter will convert as'[
   "user1",
   "user1"
]'

Comment: How would your converter xml-to-json know that it *could* be an array? Do you have an XSD?

Answer (score 0):

Singe object array for JSON is basically the same as a single object.

There is a tricky way to overcome this, that is mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23249605/8819015).

---

I would post this as a comment, but can't due to my privileges.
Thank you for your understanding !